# Running out of RAM on Google Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory, ram

I've been using Google Colaboratory to do practice simple Python coding, and then today, my Google Colab crashed because it says I'm running out of RAM, only 0.77 GB  out of 25 GB left. I moved a lot of my notebooks to trash and that didn't help. Can someone please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

RAM isn't consumed by Colab notebooks in Drive. Rather, RAM is consumed by Python variables you define in your notebook.

Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem?